# Highlight color columns on top of folds (not below)

Tags: vimrc, folding, colorcolumn, highlighting

I'm highlighting folds and color columns in colors different from the background and from each other. Here's an excerpt of my vimrc with all (potentially) relevant lines:

```
" ~/.vimrc

...

" Folding                <- maybe relevant?
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldcolumn=1
set foldclose=

...

set termguicolors
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
" colorscheme ...        <- none other than default

highlight ColorColumn guibg=darkslategray  " incomplete
highlight Folded      guibg=black          " incomplete

syntax on

...
```

This highlights the folds a bit darker than my background and the color columns a bit lighter. What bugs me is that the color columns are drawn on top of the folds, i.e., are vertically continuous, breaking up the folds in the horizontal. I'd prefer it the other way round (as in my mind it makes more sense for the color columns to be folded into the folds along with the overlying text).

**Is is possible to highlight folds on top of color columns rather than below?**

---

PS: My setup: Vim v8.2 in a PuTTY v0.73 terminal (Manjaro Virtualbox on Windows 10).

---

PPS: I'm well aware that the `highlight`s are not robust/portable in this form as they are missing entries like `ctermbg` etc. -- this is just what works in my current setup.

Comment: This would require source-level changes, AFAIK, but I would wait for one of our vim contributors to answer that